# TypeError: new_open_window() takes exactly 3 arguments (4 given) - Odoo v8 to Odoo v10 community

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-10

consider this method:

```
@api.multi
def new_open_window(list_ids, xml_id, module):
    """ Generate new window at view form or tree """
    action = self.env.ref("{}.{}".format(module, xml_id))
    result = action.read()[0]
    if isinstance(list_ids, (list, tuple)):
        result['domain'] = [('id', 'in', list_ids)]
    else:
        result['res_id'] = list_ids
    return result
```

This method is called by this one:

```
@api.multi
def create_invoice(self): 
    """ Create a invoice refund
    """
    #context = context or {}
    wizard_brw = self.browse() 
    inv_id = self._context.get('active_id')
    for wizard in wizard_brw:
        if not wizard.sure:
            raise UserError(
                _("Validation error!"),
                _("Please confirm that you know what you're doing by"
                  " checking the option bellow!"))
        if (wizard.invoice_id and wizard.invoice_id.company_id.jour_id and
                wizard.invoice_id and wizard.invoice_id.company_id.acc_id):
            inv_id = self.action_invoice_create(wizard,
                                                wizard.invoice_id)
        else:
            raise UserError(
                _('Validation error!'),
                _("You must go to the company form and configure a journal"
                  " and an account for damaged invoices"))
    return self.new_open_window([inv_id], 'action_invoice_tree1', 'account')
```

On clicking `create_invoice` button/method it throws me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 638, in _handle_exception
return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 675, in dispatch
result = self._call_function(**self.params)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 331, in _call_function
return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/service/model.py", line 119, in wrapper
return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 324, in checked_call
result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 933, in __call__
return self.method(*args, **kw)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 504, in response_wrap
response = f(*args, **kw)
File "/home/kristian/odoov10/odoo-10.0rc1c-20161005/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 866, in call_button
action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, {})
File "/home/kristian/odoov10/odoo-10.0rc1c-20161005/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 854, in _call_kw
return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/api.py", line 681, in call_kw
return call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/api.py", line 672, in call_kw_multi
result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/odoov10/gilda/l10n_ve_fiscal_requirements/wizard/wizard_invoice_nro_ctrl.py", line 138, in create_invoice
return self.new_open_window(inv_id, 'action_invoice_tree1', 'account') 
TypeError: new_open_window() takes exactly 3 arguments (4 given)
```

SO, since this uses `@api.multi` and it's a method which is called from a button, I don't know if part of the problem is the lack of `self.ensure_one()`, but I guess it's not, or not only that at least.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace :

```
def new_open_window(list_ids, xml_id, module):
```

by :

```
def new_open_window(self, list_ids, xml_id, module):
```